# No compile error without multiple inclusion guard

Tags: gcc

Not including the #ifndef guard to prevent multiple header file inclusions, does not throw compile error. Why is that?

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

#include "declare.h"
#include "declare.h" //Shouldn't I get compiler error here

int main(){

  printf("Hello World\n");

}
```

```
// declare.h

#define a 1 //just this define in declare.h file
```

Command used to compile: `gcc main.c -std=c89`

Answer (score 0):

Including a header multiple times is not an error, either with or without guards.

Guards prevent you from redefining objects and functions, when you do so.

But you haven't done that. You've just redefined a macro with the same value it had before. Which is fine.

You can test this by just compiling the following file:

```
#define a 1
#define a 1
```

It's fine.

---

> `[C89: 6.8.3]:` *[..]* An identifier currently defined as a macro without use of lparen (an object-like macro) may be redefined by another #define preprocessing directive provided that the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. *[..]*

---

Start putting more complex stuff in that header and you'll see a problem.

Comment: Thanks. But, you mention "redefining functions should throw error". But, adding a function declaration in the header file did not throw the error either. Can you provide an example as to when there could be an error?

Comment: @Vis I said redefining, not redeclaring.

Comment: @Vis — Redeclaring a function isn't a problem; redefining an enumeration or structure type is.  In older C standards (C99 or before), you could not redefine a `typedef`; in C11 and later, you can repeat a `typedef` if it refers to the same type (C11 [§6.7 ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p3)).